# relative pronouns "that" versus "where"

Tags: relative-pronouns

Sentence one: "This is the place that I remember."
Sentence two: "This is the place where we first met."

Why do we use "that" and not "where" in sentence one?
Why do we use "where" and not "that" in sentence two?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome user76539. Both sentences are correct. "that" is general and you can in many cases but "where" can only be used when you would like to describe a place, as you do. "that" is informal, and "where" is more formal. Even you can remove "that".

Comment: _Place_ is the direct object of the verb _remember_, but not of _met_. You met one another _at_ or _in_ the place.

Comment: Thank you Fredoon and thank you Kate.  Does this mean that "that" and "where" are both relative pronouns in their respective sentences?

Comment: @user76539 No: in modern grammar "that" is classified as a subordinator. The ‘missing’ relativised element is represented by a gap anaphorically linked to the antecedent, "place", i.e. “the place that I remember __".  We understand that "I remember the place", where "the place" is a noun phrase. In your second example, modern grammar classifies "where" as a preposition. We understand that “we met at/in this place", where "at/in this place" is a preposition phrase.

Comment: Hi BillJ.  Thank you very much for your detailed reply.  I sincerely appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrases, "that I remember" and "where we first met" are *relative clauses*. Relative clauses combine two clauses together by reusing part of the main clause in the relative clause.

The words "that" and "where" replace the reused part of the sentence. "That" replaces *a noun*, and "where" replaces *an adverbial phrase of location*.

"This is the place that I remember" can be broken up into two sentences:

> This is **the place**. (from the main clause)
>
> I remember **the place**. (from the relative clause)

In the relative clause, "the place" is a noun, so we replace it with "that".

"This is the place where we first met" can also be broken up into two sentences:

> This is **the place**. (from the main clause)
>
> We first met **in the place**. (from the relative clause)

In the relative clause, "in the place" is an adverbial of location (not a noun), so we replace it with "where".

Now, let's say we choose to use "that" instead of "where" in the second example sentence, like this:

> "This is the place **that** we first met."

Let's break it up into two sentences again:

> This is **the place**.
>
> We met **the place**.

"We met the place" means we didn't meet each other, but somehow two people met a location, which is nonsense.

Comment: Hi gotube.  My most sincere gratitude to you for taking time to write such an informative response to my question.  I've been confused with the topics above (still more to learn), but your explanation has helped.  Thank you.

Comment: @user76539 My sincere pleasure, and thank YOU! Few things make my day like hearing that my teaching work has helped someone finally understand something they'd been confused about.